# SQL Error: "There is already an object named XXXX in the database"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my query. What I want to do is run this query every week so table `PlanFinder.InvalidAwps` will have new records. But when I run the query it gives me this error :

```
There is already an object named 'InvalidAwps' in the database.
```

I can't change the table name. It has to remain the same. So how can I run this query every week keeping table name as it is?

```
-------------------------------------
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]')  
AND type in (N'U')) 
BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps] 
END 

SELECT DISTINCT P.Ndc Ndc, A.Price AwpUnitCost INTO PlanFinder.InvalidAwps
FROM
    PlanFinder.PlanFinder.HpmsFormulary P
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Ndc, Price FROM MHSQL01D.Drug.FdbPricing.vNdcPrices 
               WHERE PriceTypeCode = '01' AND CurrentFlag = 1) A
ON P.Ndc = A.Ndc 
WHERE (A.Ndc IS NULL OR A.Price <= 0 OR A.Price IS NULL)
AND p.Ndc IS NOT NULL 
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why go through the work of dropping and recreating the table every time? Instead, create the table once and then going forward:

```
truncate table [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]
go

insert into [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]
    (Ndc, AwpUnitCost)
    SELECT DISTINCT P.Ndc Ndc, A.Price AwpUnitCost
    FROM
        PlanFinder.PlanFinder.HpmsFormulary P
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Ndc, Price FROM MHSQL01D.Drug.FdbPricing.vNdcPrices 
                   WHERE PriceTypeCode = '01' AND CurrentFlag = 1) A
    ON P.Ndc = A.Ndc 
    WHERE (A.Ndc IS NULL OR A.Price <= 0 OR A.Price IS NULL)
    AND p.Ndc IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 on this one, it's definitely better to truncate and reload rather than dropping and re-creating the table.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your help. but let me just clear myself so each week when i would run my package, it will truncate old data from PlanFinder.invalidAwps and it will load new data from rest of the query, is it? (Sorry, Learning SQL)

Comment: Yes. Truncate will remove all existing data from the table.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your SQL checks for a table that exists in the `dbo` schema called `YourTableName` I'm guessing this should be `InvalidAwps`?  You need to change the schema and table name to match `[PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]` and you shouldn't have any problems.

As it stands you will never drop table as the schema and/or table name don't match.

Woah! It's like a completely different question now...

Maybe you need a `GO` before you start your Select statement

```
-------------------------------------
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]')  
AND type in (N'U')) 
BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps] 
END 
Go
```

Comment: The issue with the query in question is definitely the lack of a batch separator between the drop table and the insert into (the GO) as you say, but I think Joe's answer below is a better solution overall.

Comment: Thanks Barry. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the simple version:

```
if object_id('[PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]') is not null
    drop table [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]
```

Another option is to place `go` between the table drop and the insert into.

```
drop table [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]
go
select ... into [PlanFinder].[InvalidAwps]
```

SQL Server parses the SQL before it executes it, and the table still exists during parsing.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.